# Denial of Service Issue

Tags: cassandra

I found the issue below concerning inactive client connections (see [Cassandra Security](http://jkb.netii.net/index.php/pub/sinosqldb/cassandra-security)). We are using Cassandra 1.2.4 and the Cassandra JDBC driver as client. Is this still an existing issue?

Quoted from site above:

Denial of Service problem: 
Cassandra uses a Thread- Per-Client model in its network code. Since setting up a connection requires the Cassandra server to start a new thread on each connection (in addition to the TCP overhead incurred by the network), the Cassandra project recommends utilizing some sort of connection pooling. An attacker can prevent the Cassandra server from accepting new client connections by causing the Cassandra server to allocate all its resources to fake connection attempts. The only pieces of information required by an attacker are the IP addresses of the cluster members, and this information can be obtained by passively sniffing the network. The current implementation doesn’t timeout inactive connections, so any connection that is opened without actually passing data consumes a thread and a file-descriptor that are never released.

Answer (score 1):

Directly exposing Cassandra to the public network is still a bad idea, and connection pooling is still a good idea, but the [native protocol](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/binary-protocol) is fully asynchronous.

Comment: Using the native protocol would be an option for the future but it is currently not supported by the client driver we use. The main point I'm currently interested in is whether there is still no timeout for inactive connections in thrift making denial of service attacks easy by just opening new connections and never sending any data to them.